# How to use global libraries setting in Netbeans on more computers?

Tags: netbeans-7

In Netbeans I'm developing two Java projects and usually I work on two separated computers (my work is synchronized in Dropbox - both project and used Java libraries). I would like to share global libraries setting from Netbeans within these two computers. I don't want to use project based libraries setting, because some libraries are commonly used in another projects and I don't want to duplicate them in Library Manager.

Is there some way how to place global library setting file on different location (in Dropbox folder in my situation) and use it with more installations of Netbeans IDE?